# Criando um bot em JS

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um bot em **javascript** onde ele irá inserir um valor em um campo de um site e clicar em 'enviar'.

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
    document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = 'javascript';
    document.getElementById('gbqfb').click();
}
```

Porém encontrei um código semelhante a esse na internet, ele abre a página porem não insere no campo de busca o valor e clica em 'ir'. Alguém teria uma ideia semelhante a essa 'não solução'?

Comment: Só dá para fazer isso na forma de uma extensão de browser ou bookmarklet, ou se você achar uma maneira de injetar scripts no site desejado (alguma vulnerabilidade que permita XSS).

Comment: Em alguma outra programação é possível fazer esse acesso e enviar uma informação simulando um usuário digitando no campo?

Comment: Um bookmarklet não resolve?

Comment: @ralfting qualquer linguagem que tenha comunicação TCP/IP teoricamente permite, com maior ou menor complexidade. Seria melhor você explicar o que está tentando fazer, pra poder indicar o melhor caminho.

Comment: cara talvez vc consiga executar pelo console do navegador. O google chrome permite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Através do javascript executando dentro do contexto de uma página (e limitado pelo sandbox do navegador) não é possível manipular documentos vindos de outro domínio, seja em uma nova janela ou em um iframe. Isso é por motivos de segurança.

---

Se você quer uma resposta visual para isso: ver a janela do browser abrindo e os comandos sendo executados (talvez para repassar o controle para o usuário depois que chegar em algum dado estado, como depois de clicar em pesquisar), tem basicamente duas soluções:

1. Uma extensão ao navegador:

   Extensões podem injetar código em uma página específica (como inserir um botão a mais na página do google), ou adicionar um botão direto na barra do navegador, ou teclas de atalho. Qualquer um desses pode ser gatilho para iniciar a ação: manipular o DOM da página.

   O ponto negativo é que terá que fazer uma extensão para cada navegador que queira suportar, possivelmente usando APIs completamente diferentes.
2. Biblioteca de automação:

   Usar um programa externo que vai lançar um novo processo do navegador e vai "controlar" ele. Isso é suportado por todos os grandes navegadores e é relativamente simples de programar. Duas boas bibliotecas: [**Selenium**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) e [**Watir**](http://watir.com/).

---

Por último, talvez você não queira um navegador visível ou a iteração com o usuário. Queira fazer tudo as escuras e apenas obter o resultado depois (um array dos títulos dos resultados da pesquisa, por exemplo). Para isso você precisa de um navegador ***headless***.

1. [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/):

   Como já mencionado em outras respostas. É uma interface ao WebKit, mas sem criar uma janela ou visual de nenhum tipo. Você fica no controle de tudo.
2. Implementar o seu HTTP Client:

   Aqui pode usar qualquer linguagem que queira. Basta abrir um socket TCP e se comunicar com o servidor do site usando o protocolo HTTP. O grande problema aqui é que o javascript da página não será executado e terá que processar o HTML manualmente, você estará muito limitado. Por outro lado é a forma mais rápida e eficiente de obter dados. Você pode fazer uma única request ao [`http://www.google.com/search?q=teste`](http://www.google.com/search?q=teste) por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o **[PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/)** para simular o browser, usando scripts feitos usando javascript.

O que é possível fazer com o PhantomJs:

- automação de navegação (provavelmente é isso que você quer)
- testes de websites
- tirar screenshots
- converter página para PDF

O projeto usa o código do webkit, e permite fazer várias coisas usando scripts em javascript. **Não é necessário ter nenhum navegador instalado** na máquina em que o PhantomJs for instalado.

### Ideia para fazer funcionar no Browser

Apesar de poder fazer o robô usando javascript como linguagem, esse robô não vai rodar a partir de uma página web, mas sim, a partir de um programa executável desktop.

Entretanto, seria possível, criar um web-service que chame o PhantomJs, fazendo isso ser possível através do navegador, que chamaria o web-service.

Você pode fazer o web service usando o C# por exemplo, que tem suporte ao PhantonJs através de uma biblioteca.

Answer (score 1):

O navegador NÃO irá permitir isso, devido à caixa de areia - é uma restrição de segurança de qualquer browser.

Usar o http://phantomjs.org para poder manipular páginas nativas é uma alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recentemente tive a oportunidade de trabalhar com esta biblioteca/solução: http://www.gebish.org/ que recorre a drivers do Selenium, suportando automatização pelo Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera, htmlUnit, PhantomJS e outros.

A linguagem utilizada para a automatização dos testes é Groovy (baseada em java), recorrendo a uma biblioteca de navegação que suporta selectores semelhantes aos conhecidos selectores JQuery.

Recomendo começar por aqui como exemplo: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle